# print('Tax cost: ' + str(tax)) I dont understand the use of + before str in this code

Tags: python-3.x

In this code, why do I need to use '+' before `str(tax)`?

```
cost = input('What is the cost?')


rate = input('What is the tax rate? (in %)')

div = float(rate) / 100

tax = float(div) * float(cost)

tc = tax + float(cost)

print('Tax cost: ' + str(tax))
print('Total cost: ' + str(tc))
```

Comment: Use [f-Strings: A New and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python) instead.  `print(f'Tax cost: {tax}')`, then there is no need for `+` or `str(tax)`.

Answer (score 0):

In `'Tax cost: ' + str(tax)`, the `+` is before `str(tax)` to concatenate / combine both strings. If you're wondering why we need to use `str(tax)` at all, it's because `tax` is a float, and cannot be concatenated with a string.

Answer (score 0):

@Axiumin_ , I think you mean "concatenate" ?

You can avoid calling print twice by concatenating the first with the second, and using a newline \n.

```
print( 'Tax cost: ' + str(tax) + "\nTotal cost: ' + str(tc) )
```